# How to create a Drawable from a stream without resizing it?

Tags: android

If I have the minimum target SDK for my app set to 4 then all calls to Drawable.createFromStream resize images.

e.g. if the source image is 480px wide and the Android device my app is running on has a density of 1.5 then the following code returns a BitmapDrawable with a width of 320

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.examples.com/something.png");

Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(url.openStream(), "something.png");
```

Is there a method to force it to be unchanged or specify the scale (ldpi/mdpi/hdpi etC) to return an image from an InputStream?

Edit: Solution from below.

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
b.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can load image as Bitmap. This way its size will be unchanged.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...)
```

Or you can try `BitmapDrawable(InputStream is)` constructor. It is deprecated but I guess it should do the job.

Comment: I would go with the `BitmapDrawable()` method as it goes straight to the point.  It's deprecated, but not for API level 4.  Ideally you would use `BitmapDrawable(Resource, InputStream)`, but that's not available to you until API level 5.  Another option is to do something like `BitmapDrawable(Resource, new BitmapFactory().decodeStream(InputStream))` which is available at API level 4 (but not less).

Comment: This works thanks. I've added an edit to show how to convert to BitmapDrawable.

Answer (score 2):

**Loading images from local resource in ImageView Adapter**

I was stuck with OOM error in ion by Koushik Dutta, for as low as 2 images, loading from the resource folder. Even he mentioned it may happen since they are not streams of data. and suggested to load them as InputStream.

I chucked ion Library since i wanted just 4 images from the local.

here is the solution with simple ImageView.

inside the RecyclerViewAdapter/ or any where

```
 InputStream inputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.your_id);

    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    b.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
    holder.mImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Although **Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);** is deprecated but, does the job quite well.

so instead we can directly get drawable from InputStream just by this line..

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream,"src");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

After a long time, I came across the following solution. It works. It retrieves creates bitmap from file at locallink.

```
private Drawable getDrawableForStore(String localLink) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = null;
    try {
        File filePath = this.getFileStreamPath(localLink);
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("getThumbnail() on internal storage", ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    float scaledDensity = metrics.density;
    int width = thumbnail.getWidth();
    int height = thumbnail.getHeight();

    if(scaledDensity<1){

        width = (int) (width *scaledDensity);
        height = (int) (height *scaledDensity);
    }else{
        width = (int) (width +width *(scaledDensity-1));
        height = (int) (height +height *(scaledDensity-1));
    }

    thumbnail = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, width, height, true);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),thumbnail);

    return d;

}
```