# how do I transform a string of url's into drawable?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-image, android-webservice

I currently have an arraylist as follows:

```
private void loadImages() {
        images = new ArrayList<>();

        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imag1));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imag2));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imag3));
}
```

I want to be able to convert a url into these drawables such that:

```
 drawable1 = "http.someimage.com/image.png"
 drawable2 = "http.someimage.com/newimage.png"
```

followed by

```
private void loadImages() {
            images = new ArrayList<>();

            images.add(getResources().getDrawable(drawable1));
            images.add(getResources().getDrawable(drawable2));
...etc    }
```

Is there any easy way to go around this? I definitely want to stick to drawables ,but I cant find any way to convert a url to drawable
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a URL of the picture you need to download it first.

You can't "convert" a URL into a drawable.

you need something like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http.someimage.com/image.png"); 
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Then if you need to add the image into an ImageView object you can call the method .setImageBitmap(bmp).
Otherwise there are ways to extract a Drawable object from the Bitmap
you can check this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361976/how-to-create-a-drawable-from-a-stream-without-resizing-it). then once you have the drawable you can add it to your arraylist.

Hope I got your question right

P.S.: be sure not to do this on main thread since it is a network operation! use a thread or an asynctask

Comment: I did look at that answer but didnt work for me as expected.Can you show me with respect to my code for arraylist for a couple of images.

Comment: Once you obtain the Bitmap you need to convert it to a Drawable object. To make it for two images you just need to double the code snippet I posted you above. to convert Bitmaps to Drawables you can use [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html)