# Android create file from drawable

Tags: android, file

Is there any way to create file from image drawable to send it via `MultypartEntity`? I having error all the time.

```
fileUri =  Uri.parse("android.resource://com.wellbread/drawable/placeholder_avatar.png");
mCurrentPhotoPath = fileUri.toString();


 java.io.FileNotFoundException: android.resource:/com.wellbread/drawable/placeholder_avatar.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-25 12:01:53.134    3663-3684/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
```

Comment: 1- copy drawable image into sdcard and then create your further steps.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895073/create-a-file-from-drawable

Comment: Do you read my answer yet?

Comment: Yes, great! It works but actually not creating file, so it would be great if there is any way to create File from byte[] that I don't know

Comment: If you have byte array already, no need to create File object, you can post byte array by using the implementation of addBinaryBody(...) in my answer. The bitmapdata is byte array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following sample code:

```
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_home);
        if (drawable != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            final byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
            String url = "http://10.0.2.2/api/fileupload";
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            // Add binary body
            if (bitmapdata != null) {
                ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("image/png");
                String fileName = "ic_action_home.png";
                builder.addBinaryBody("file", bitmapdata, contentType, fileName);
                httpEntity = builder.build();
                ...
            }
        ...
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
try
        {
        File f=new File("file name");
       InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(id); // id drawable
        OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
        out.write(buf,0,len);
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){}
        }
```

Comment: And what is "file name" then? I am actually looking for file. And you say it must be in raw folder?

Comment: In your answer i need to put a String path to file, but the question is that my new file all  the time says it can't find it.

Comment: Это имя и путь файла куда он сохранится из drawable

Answer (score 1):

You can open an InputStream from your drawable resource using following code:

```
     try 
        { 
        File f=new File("your file name");
//id is some like R.drawable.b_image
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(id);
        OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
        out.write(buf,0,len);
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e){}
        }
```

Comment: What to use as a file name?

Comment: In your answer i need to put a String path to file, but the question is that my new file all  the time says it can't find it.

Comment: file name can be something like this ==> File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName); and file name may be something like temp.png

Answer (score 1):

You have to get Bitmap from drawable:

```
public static Bitmap decodeAndSetWidthHeight(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight){
        Bitmap btm = BitmapHelper.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(res, resId, reqWidth, reqHeight);
        return decodeAndSetWidthHeight(btm, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    }
```

Then you can create file from bitmap

```
    public static File bitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap){
        File outFile = FileHelper.getImageFilePNG();
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return outFile;
    }
```

UPDATE (sorry, forget to provide some methods):

```
public static File getImageFilePNG() {
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/any name folder");
    dir.mkdirs();

    String fileName = String.format("%d.png", System.currentTimeMillis());
    return new File(dir, fileName);
}


 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    Log.d("ANT", "options.inSampleSize : " + options.inSampleSize);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

 public static Bitmap decodeAndSetWidthHeight(Bitmap btm, int reqWidth, int reqHeight){
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    RectF inRect = new RectF(0, 0, btm.getWidth(), btm.getHeight());
    RectF outRect = new RectF(0, 0, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    m.setRectToRect(inRect, outRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
    float[] values = new float[9];
    m.getValues(values);

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(btm, (int) (btm.getWidth() * values[0]), (int) (btm.getHeight() * values[4]), true);
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell what to use as file name for created file? Maybe some full path?

Comment: In your answer i need to put a String path to file, but the question is that my new file all  the time says it can't find it.